# JQuery to override div element

Tags: html, jquery, apexcharts

I have my snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/4h1Leyco/2/)

Two questions on that :

1. I have challenge in overriding the  element when a selection is clicked, the Apexchart loaded is flashed only.

Trying this codes but seems don't help.

```
        $('#inventoryChart').empty()
    inventoryAll.render();
```

Please advise.

2. Is there any effective steps to simplify this code:

```
    $('.menu-link-option').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).text();

        switch (href) {
            case "All Inventory":
                $('#inventoryChart').empty()
                inventoryAll.render();
                break;
            case "By Department":
                $('#inventoryChart').empty()
                inventoryByDept.render();
                break;
            case "By Location":
                inventoryByLocation.render();
                break;
        }


    });
```

The idea is when a selection is made, then straight to execute the chart and show it in element.

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [apexcharts](/questions/tagged/apexcharts) still thinks you want it to render the first chart, so draws itself back in.

There is a `.destroy()` method, but your code only generates the charts on first load, so destroying them would break that.

To have minimal changes to your code, I suggest having different containers for each chart and then showing them as required:

```
<div class="chart">
    <div id="inventoryChart1"></div>
    <div id="inventoryChart2"></div>
</div>
```

then

```
case "All Inventory":
    $('.chart>div').hide();
    $("#inventoryChart1").show();
    inventoryAll.render();
    break;
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6sk5d7hL/

Comment: Hi, when I click the hyperlink > 1 time. The chart is stacked.